# Deserializing an object in symfony return an exception

Tags: php, json, symfony

i follow the Serializer component documentation, to turn specific json into object
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-an-object
I make this call to receive a list of objects.

```
$response = $httpClient->request('GET', 'https://www.example.com/web/app.php/api/articles?next=1&Type=ep');
dump($response->getContent());
```

So I have an list of Article Objects.

```
{
    "header": {
        "error": 0,
        "message": "ok",
        "next": 2
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 17007,
            "title": "test article title 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 17008,
            "title": "sample article 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to deserialize the results part... The problem is that the Symfony Serializer gives me one null object

```
$encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
$normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
$articles = $serializer->deserialize($response->getContent(), Article::class, 'json');
```

what is the probleme please ?

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Since this kind of question appears from time to time, and it's not entirely clear, why it's not clear where the problem lies:

```php7
    $serializer->deserialize($response->getContent(), Article::class, 'json');
```

that line expects the response content to look like this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title of just this one article"
}
```

which obviously doesn't match the response content you posted . So you essentially have two options:

#### 1. peel back the json wrapper

deserialization is the combination of decoding and denormalization ([see your link, but first paragraphs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)), so we can do the interim peeling back:

```php7
$normalized = $serializer->decode($response->getContent(), 'json');
$articlesNormalized = $normalized['results'] ?? [];
$articles = $serializer->denormalize($articlesNormalized, Article::class . '[]');
```

see [this part about handling arrays](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-arrays) for the reason on why you need to add `. '[]'`;

#### 2. deserialize into the correct class:

Since the articles are wrapped, you might need to wrap as well ... - you might need annotation reader for this to work ...

disclaimer: I haven't tested this, but it should work ...

```php7
class ArticleResponse {
    /** @var array */
    public $header;
    /** @var Article[] */ // <-- maybe this needs to be []Article, I'm never sure.
    public $results;
}
```

and now you can do:

```php7
$articleResponse = $serializer->deserialize($response->getContent(), ArticleResponse::class, 'json');
$articles = $articleResponse->articles;
```